# Qt Creator: is there something like VS solution in which you can add projects and set project dependencies and build order?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have one of the latest versions of Qt Creator.

1. is there something like VS solution? In which you can add projects and set project dependencies and build order?
2. if I have multiple open projects, how do I set one of them as "default", so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> builds specifically that project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think the "solution" you are looking for is the project_name.pro.user file that gets created when you open a .pro file in QtCreator. It's an XML file that describes build steps, build environment, etc. for your project. When your project is open in QtCreator, go in the "Projects" tab (from the left), then in the "Dependencies" tab, where you can check all other (open) projects that this project depends on, and thus must be built first. You can repeat for each project, then QtCreator will figure a build order that satisfies all dependencies (unless there are cyclic dependencies).
2. Go in the "Projects" tab (on the left), then select the project you want to be "default" from the top bar, and go back in Edit mode. The project you selected will show in bold in the project sidebar, which means it's the one tied to the "Build project" shortcut.

Comment: umm.... .pro files can hardly be considered XML.... http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-project-files.html

Comment: @Timothy Baldridge: In my sentence, "it" refers to "the project_name.pro.user file that gets created when you open a .pro file in QtCreator". It does not refer to the .pro file. Now, have a look at a .pro.user file, and you will notice that it is indeed XML.

Comment: In the "Projects" view, the "default" project can also be set from the right-click menu, option "Set as Active Project".